# Python upscaling an image (no external library help)

Tags: python, numpy, image-resizing

I'm trying to upscale the image by 200% but there's some weird bars over the output image. I figure it has something to do with the center pixel. I'm trying to do it without library functions such as resize(). For reference, I'm trying to implement this functionality:

[image]

```
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('C:\\Users\\usama\\Downloads\\lena.tiff',0)             # Open Image in grayscale
origImg = np.asarray(img)                   # Convert Image to 2D Array
upscaledImg = np.zeros((1024,1024))         # Empty Array for upscaled Image

rowOld = 0            # Orignal Image Row
rowNew = 0            # Upscaled Image Row
colOld = 0            # Original Image Column
colNew = 0            # Upscaled Image Column

def pixeltop():
    return int(origImg[rowOld][colOld]) / 2 + int(origImg[rowOld][colOld + 1]) / 2

def pixelcenter():
    return (int(origImg[rowOld+1][colOld]) + int(origImg[rowOld+1][colOld + 1]) + int(origImg[rowOld+1][colOld]) + int(origImg[rowOld][colOld + 1]))/5

def pixelleft():
    return int(origImg[rowOld][colOld]) / 2 + int(origImg[rowOld + 1][colOld]) / 2

def pixelright():
    return int(origImg[rowOld][colOld + 1]) / 2 + int(origImg[rowOld + 1][colOld + 1]) / 2

def pixelbottom():
    return int(origImg[rowOld + 1][colOld]) / 2 + int(origImg[rowOld + 1][colOld + 1]) / 2

while rowOld < (len(origImg)):                # Outer Loop for transversing rows
  colOld = 0
  colNew = 0
  while colOld < (len(origImg)):              # Inner Loop for transversing columns
    upscaledImg[rowNew][colNew] = origImg[rowOld][colOld]
    upscaledImg[rowNew][colNew+1] = pixeltop()
    upscaledImg[rowNew][colNew+2] = origImg[rowOld][colOld+1]
    upscaledImg[rowNew+1][colNew] = pixelleft()
    upscaledImg[rowNew+1][colNew+1] = pixelcenter()
    upscaledImg[rowNew+1][colNew+2] = pixelright()
    upscaledImg[rowNew+2][colNew] = origImg[rowOld+1][colOld]
    upscaledImg[rowNew+2][colNew+1] = pixelbottom()
    upscaledImg[rowNew+2][colNew+2] = origImg[rowOld+1][colOld+1]
    colOld +=2
    colNew +=4

    if(rowOld == 511):
      break
  rowOld += 2
  rowNew += 4

cv2.imwrite('upscaled.png',upscaledImg)
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the new image is constructed by modifying windows of 3x3 pixels, but your window is moving 4 pixel by 4 pixels, leaving a gap of one pixel, hence the black bars.

example just focusing on row:

we start with rownew=0

-> Img[0] is set

-> Img[0+1] is set

->img[0+2] is set

now rownew+=4

-> Img[4+0] is set

->Img[4+1] is set

->Img[4+2] is set

leaving Img[3] blank

You could either change the padding of your window to be 3 or implement assignations to have a 4x4 window

Comment: Ohhh right, I didn't think of it like that. Just implemented this and now it's solved. Thanks.